# How long should I wait before accepting an answer?

Tags: discussion, support

I recently asked two questions for which I would like to receive multiple answers:

- [What are some results in Economics that are both a consensus and far from common sense?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/20992/what-are-some-results-in-economics-that-are-both-a-consensus-and-far-from-common)
- [What are some important mathematics results that were first developed in Economics?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/20994/what-are-some-important-mathematics-results-that-were-first-developed-in-economi)

How long can I wait to accept one? If someone gives a good answer, but I would like to get other answers anyway, is it disrespectful or against the rules to delay the acceptance for a while?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any rule about this.  My view is that it's good practice to wait a few days after posting a question before accepting an answer.  The advantages of this are:

1. It allows time for more answers to be posted, and for those answers to be compared, and the best can then be accepted.
2. It allows time for comments and voting on the answers, which may help in identifying which is best.
3. While it is possible to withdraw an acceptance and accept another answer, an early acceptance could have the effect of discouraging further answers (which may be illogical but my impression is that is does sometimes have that effect).

Answer (score 2):

Standard procedure is to accept an answer when there is one that you feel has addressed your question. If a better answer comes along later, you can always switch to accepting the new one instead.